# Is there a listing of XML MS Word 2007 ribbon control names?

Tags: xml, ms-word, ribbon-control

I'd like to simplify my Word 2007 ribbon by hiding some of its tabs, groups, and controls. So I'm learning how to use XML to do this. The script I've built (with the help of Greg Maxey's excellent site, https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html) checks out as well formed. I've saved it in Word's STARTUP directory. But when I open Word, I get a Custom UI runtime error saying "Error found in Custom UI XML of "C:\Users\wardw\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP\Hide References and Mailing and Some Inserts.dotm":
Line: 9
Column: 55
Error Code 0x80004005
Unknown Office control ID: Shapes

Clicking OK repeatedly gets the same message, except the control IDs are SmartArt, Chart, Cross-reference, and ClipArt. I got those names from the Insert tab groups Illustrations and Links, as shown in my script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabReferences" visible="false" />
      <tab idMso="TabMailings" visible="false" />
      <tab idMso="TabInsert"> 
         <group idMso="GroupInsertIllustrations">
             <control idMso="Shapes" visible="false" />
             <control idMso="SmartArt" visible="false" />
             <control idMso="Chart" visible="false" />
             <control idMso="Cross-reference" visible="false" />
             <control idMso="ClipArt" visible="false" />
          </group>
       </tab>
     </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

If I'm assigning the wrong names, is there a listing of the correct names to use in XML scripts for hiding Word's ribbon items?

Comment: A good starting place is Appendix B of RibbonX: Customizing the Office 2007 Ribbon. http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ISBN=0470191112/balancecheckbookA/  http://site.thehousewaresstore.com/oodle/AccessBooks/Wiley.RibbonX.Customizing.the.Office.2007.Ribbon.Jan.2008.pdf Unfortunately, that is not going to tell you any different names.

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing a listing of Control IDs for the Ribbon Interface of 2007. The first I recall is for 2010. You can download that one here. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627

Comment: Thanks, Charles and Rich. I tried Rich's link, but the page tried really hard to sell Office 365, and I couldn't locate the humble listing I needed.

Comment: There’s a red Download button on the page. Maybe you didn’t scroll down past Microsoft’s banner ad for Microsoft 365? The download is for Excel files for all the Office apps and they contain the control id names. The Download is not for getting Microsoft 365.

Answer (score 3):

You can download the full package of Ribbon Control IDs from the links below. There are currently three packages, Office 2016, Office 2013, and Office 2010. It appears that a download link to a package of control Ids for Office 2007 has been deactivated and I haven’t found anything published at this time about Office 2019 control ids.

The download packages include Excel files by Office application and in each file are the Control Ids organized by ribbon tab and then within the sequence they appear within the tab.

Office 2016: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745

Office 2013: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798

Office 2010: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627